# source code syntax highlighting for trac?

Tags: svn, trac, pygments

I've installed `trac` on my Ubuntu server but there is no `php` syntax highlighting.

I have installed `Pygments` using `apt-get install` but how do I configure `trac` so it uses highlighting in the svn source browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trac should automatically detect pygments, assuming its installed in the same Python instance. You may want to have a look at the [doc](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSyntaxColoring), particularly the bit about the [mimeviewer section](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracIni#mimeviewer-section) of trac.ini and make sure everything is ok.

The two most likely candidates I can think of are:

1) the PHP mime type is not properly registered or (even worse) your files were committed to svn with the svn property `svn:mime-type` set to `text/plain` (I had this happen on a large project, but resetting the mime-type property worked (Trac uses the file extension as a fallback if the mimetype isn't reported by the VCS).

2) Everything may be working, but the default style may not be working properly. Try adjusting the highlighting style either through the /prefs page on your Trac instance or through the `pygments_default_style` setting in trac.ini.